# Dynamically ordering by string

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I've created an extension on IQueryable as I would like to order by nullable datetimes first then order by the datetime itself using just the string of the property i.e "activeTo". I've created the code below:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Sort<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortBy)
    {
        //create the expression tree that represents the generic parameter to the predicate
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        //create an expression tree that represents the expression p=>p.SortField.HasValue 
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, sortBy);

        var target = Expression.Constant(null, prop.Type);
        var bin = Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Convert(target, prop.Type));

        var exp = Expression.Lambda(bin, param);

        string method = "OrderBy";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { source.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, source.Expression, exp);

        //now do the ThenBy bit,sending in the above expression to the Expression.Call
        exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        types = new Type[] { source.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        method = "ThenBy";
        var ThenByCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, orderByCallExpression, exp);


        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(ThenByCallExpression);
    }
```

This extension is called by:

```
query.Sort("activeTo");
```

Which then gives the below the response:

```
 {
      "title": "test 5",
      "activeFrom": "2019-06-08T21:26:50.2833333",
      "activeTo": "2019-06-08T21:26:50.2833333",
 },
 {
      "title": "test 2",
      "activeFrom": "2019-06-08T21:28:45.65",
      "activeTo": null,
 }
```

I'd expect the record with activeTo as null to be first however, this isn't the case.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code constructs the expression `OrderBy(p => p.activeTo == null)` and `true` comes after `false` as `false` is ordinally represented by 0 and `true` by 1. Therefore your expression first collects all values different from null, and then all values being null. However, shouldn’t your method generate an expression like`OrderBy(p => p.activeTo)` instead, which seems more fitting for a name like Sort?

Comment: @ckuri Yes your right, I was thinking of creating another extension which would order by nullable but im not sure what to do

Comment: I have seen that you are actually generating `OrderBy(p => p.activeTo == null).ThenBy(p => activeTo == null)`. Why? Just the OrderBy suffices.

Comment: @ckuri My bad, that's a mistake. I want to actually do OrderBy(p => p.activeTo == null).ThenBy(p => activeTo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments the goal seems to be to dynamically generate an expression which sorts `null` values to the front.

The current code produces the following expression `OrderBy(p => p.activeTo == null).ThenBy(p => p.activeTo == null)`. This has two flaws:

- It sorts `null` values to the front as the bools sort order is `false`, `true` (as their ordinal values are 0 and 1, respectively). Therefore a comparison to `null` first collects the `false` cases, and then the `true`cases.
- The `ThenBy` repeats the `OrderBy`, but was actually intended to emit `ThenBy(p => p.ActiveTo)`.

The first can be solved by either using `Expression.NotEqual` instead of `Expression.Equal` for `p => p != p.activeTo` or by using `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`.
In total the code should be:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Sort<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string sortBy)
{
    //create the expression tree that represents the generic parameter to the predicate
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

    //create an expression tree that represents the expression p=>p.SortField.HasValue 
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, sortBy);

    var target = Expression.Constant(null, prop.Type);
    // NotEqual, to sort nulls before not-nulls
    var bin = Expression.NotEqual(prop, Expression.Convert(target, prop.Type));

    var exp = Expression.Lambda(bin, param);

    // OrderBy with the null comparison expression
    string method = nameof(Queryable.OrderBy);
    Type[] types = new Type[] { source.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    var orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, source.Expression, exp);

    // ThenBy with the property expression
    exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
    types = new Type[] { source.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    method = nameof(Queryable.ThenBy);
    var ThenByCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, orderByCallExpression, exp);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(ThenByCallExpression);
}
```

This yields the following expression:
`OrderBy(p => p.activeTo != null).ThenBy(p => p.activeTo)`.

**Remarks**: It should be noted that usually `OrderBy(p => p.activeTo)` would already sort null values to the front, as this is the default sort order for strings, nullables, and so on. However, this behavior could be overwritten depending by the specific type and depend on the query source. Therefore, I left it like the OP has.

Comment: The yielded expression is not exactly what I want to achieve. Instead, I want to grab all records which are null first then sort the remaining by the actual value. Therefore I changed: `Expression.NotEqual(prop, Expression.Convert(target, prop.Type));` to `Expression.Equa(prop, Expression.Convert(target, prop.Type));` but still the null value is last in my result

Comment: The `NotEqual` is the crucial point that sorts null values to the front, `Equal` sorts them to the end like I have explained.

Comment: Using `NotEqual` doesn't work, this is where I thought it was wrong so I decided to change it to `Equal`